# How do I use system.reactive to perform a do while that uses a value from within per-iteration?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

For the sake of example, let's assume I've decided to start with the following:

```
var startingSequence = await GetLastSequence(database);

return Observable.Create<ExternalSourceChange>(async (observer) =>
{
    var currentSequence = startingSequence;

    var done = false;
    do
    {
        var changes = await CreateRequest()
            .AppendPathSegment(database)
            .AppendPathSegment("_changes")
            .SetQueryParams(new
            {
                since = currentSequence,
                include_docs = "true",
                limit = 1,
            })
            .GetJsonAsync<ExternalSourceChangeJson>();

        // note: If we've already processed past this sequence, skip it.
        if (string.CompareOrdinal(changes.last_seq, currentSequence) <= 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var result = changes.results.First();
        var deleted = result.doc.GetValue("_deleted")?.Value<bool>() ?? false;

        var databaseChange = new ExternalSourceChangeJson(result.id, result.doc.ToString())
        {
            Deleted = deleted,
        };

        observer.OnNext(databaseChange);

        currentSequence = ((List<ExternalSourceChangeListJson>)changes
            .results)
            .OrderBy((result) => result.seq)
            .LastOrDefault()?.seq
            ?? currentSequence;

        done = changes.pending == 0;

    } while (! done);

    await SetLastSequence(database, currentSequence);

    observer.OnCompleted();

    // note: Not sure I have anything to do here.
    return () => {};
});
```

Is there anything I can do with the above to golf it into leveraging more of `system.reactive`?

- `Changes<dynamic>` is produced on each iteration
- `currentSequence` and `done` are by far the two things I feel like I could be doing a better job of managing

Comment: Why not define just a `Subject<MyPayloadType>` and call `OnNext()` with the `results.Payload` value?

Comment: Hmm, maybe?  I'm not sure how I'd wire in the use of `results.NextPageHash` in that case though so that I could tie the lifecycle of `currentPageHash` in as part of the stream?

Comment: `currentSequence` doesn't look like it's changing. Is it supposed to change? Could you clarify or post an MVCE?

Comment: For sure, apologies.  Example is now updated with what I'm currently using (and it works).

Comment: Using `Observable.Create` is not the way to go here. If ever you find yourself returning `return () => {}` or `return Disposable.Empty;` then you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Observable.Create` is not the way to go here. If ever you find yourself returning `return () => {};` (or `return Disposable.Empty;` which you see a lot) then you're doing something wrong.

There's almost always a way to use the built-in operators to get a good resilient query.

Now, since you've got a lot going on in your query that I can't easily replicate I'm going to make a simplified example of how you might do what you want.

To start with here's my extreme simplification for getting something from the database:

```
private static int __counter = 0;
public Task<int> GetCounterAsync() => Task.Run(() => __counter++);
```

Now I'm going to code up the wrong approach, based on your code, so that you can see how my final code will relate to yours. My goal here is to retrieve values from the "database" until I get a `10` and finish with that value.

```
IObservable<int> query =
    Observable.Create<int>(async observer =>
    {
        var done = false;
        do
        {
            var counter = await GetCounterAsync();
            observer.OnNext(counter);
            done = counter == 10;
        } while (!done);
        observer.OnCompleted();
        return () => { };
    });
```

This is designed to look like your code. I want to stress that this is **not the way to do it.**

Here's the correct way.

```
IObservable<int> query =
    Observable
        .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => GetCounterAsync()))
        .Repeat()
        .TakeUntil(x => x == 10);
```

The `Observable.Defer` is important as it causes the `Observable.FromAsync(() => GetCounterAsync())` to be called anew each time the `.Repeat()` operator is triggered. Without it the result of the first call to `Observable.FromAsync(() => GetCounterAsync())` is repeated indefinitely.

Now, if you need to include state within your query, which is often a reason that people use `Observable.Create`, then you can always wrap the whole thing in another `Observable.Defer`.

```
IObservable<int> query =
    Observable
        .Defer(() =>
        {
            var finish = 10;
            return
                Observable
                    .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => GetCounterAsync()))
                    .Repeat()
                    .TakeUntil(x => x == finish);
        });
```

In this way any state that is needed in your query is created again for each and every subscriber.

If you then need to do anything with the state at the end, you can do this:

```
IObservable<int> query =
    Observable
        .Defer(() =>
        {
            var finish = 10;
            return
                Observable
                    .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => GetCounterAsync()))
                    .Repeat()
                    .TakeUntil(x => x == finish)
                    .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine($"Finished at {finish}"));
        });

query.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

That produces:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Finished at 10
```

Let me know if this helps or if there's something I've missed in your question.

Comment: I'll try to adapt your suggestions to what I have and report back, looks promising though!  Also, I absolutely appreciate your simplification, that's honestly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could make it more robust, by including error handling and reacting to unsubscription.

```
return Observable.Create<ExternalSourceChange>(observer =>
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var fireAndForget = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                var changes = await CreateRequest().GetJsonAsync();
                //...
                observer.OnNext(databaseChange);
                //...
                if (changes.pending == 0) break;
            }
            observer.OnCompleted();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex) when (ex.CancellationToken == cts.Token)
        {
            // Do nothing (the subscriber unsubscribed)
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            observer.OnError(ex);
        }
    });

    return System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable.Create(() =>
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    });
});
```

You could pass the `cts.Token` to any async methods you call that accept cancellation tokens, for even faster termination of the loop.

---

**Update:** I just noticed another overload of the `Observable.Create` method, that accepts an async delegate with `CancellationToken` parameter:

```
// Summary:
// Creates an observable sequence from a specified cancellable asynchronous Subscribe
// method. The CancellationToken passed to the asynchronous Subscribe method is
// tied to the returned disposable subscription, allowing best-effort cancellation.
public static IObservable<TResult> Create<TResult>(
    Func<IObserver<TResult>, CancellationToken, Task> subscribeAsync);
```

This could be used to simplify things, by getting rid of the fire-and-forget task, the `CancellationTokenSource` and the `Disposable.Create` at the end.

```
return Observable.Create<ExternalSourceChange>(async (observer, cancellationToken) =>
{ // etc...
```

Comment: You've clearly thought about this. That's good. I'd avoid the `cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`, though, and just go with a `if (changes.pending == 0 || cts.IsCancellationRequested) break;`. I don't think it's great idea to throw like that if it can be avoided.

Comment: @Enigmativity I wanted to avoid calling `observer.OnCompleted()` in case of unsubscription, although in may not be important.

Comment: Just check the token again. Throwing exceptions is usually a bad idea if they can be avoided.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, or I could do `if (cts.IsCancellationRequested) return`. But if the token is passed to `GetJsonAsync()` then I will have to catch the exception anyway. Normally creating/subscribing/unsubscribing to observables is not something that happens in tight loops, so I don't think that matters too much.

Comment: If the exception happens in a different thread, does the thread get interrupted when the exception fires? If it does then that can cause issues. If it doesn't then the code can wait to inspect the token in the loop.

Comment: @Enigmativity I agree with you in general. The reason I would stick to the `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` pattern in this case is for having a single exit point from the method in case of unsubscription. I see it as a compromise between efficiency and simplicity.